# camel cxf - error handling - how to keep exchange properties

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am using camel cxf to send message to a service.I am using doTry/doCatch to handle error from the service.
I notice that when I'm getting an error from the service I do not have anymore my properties in the exchange (the ones I put in the exchange I sent to the service).
Why is that ? anyway to keep the exchange properties ?
this is the code :

```
<doTry>
       <to
              uri="cxf:bean:finishWSEndpoint?defaultOperationName=saveManufactureData" />
       <doCatch>
              <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
             <handled>
                    <constant>false</constant>
             </handled>
             <bean ref="finishService" method="onCxfException" />
       </doCatch>
</doTry>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by exchange properties, as it sounds like you mixup that with message headers. Show us the code you use to set those "properties"

Comment: yes you are right - there was some error in my code